# The specified value "2017-00-06" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tenho um campo preenchido com date:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtValidadeIni" runat="server"
   CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="10" type="date" name="date" 
   pattern="[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$" min="1970-01-01" max="2100-02-18">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Quando o usuário preenche e salva num campo tipo date no sql corretamente, fica salvo desta forma : "2017-10-06"
Porém quando tento trazer este campo do banco para ser mostrado no formulário ele ta me retornando o seguinte erro:

> The specified value "2017-00-06" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

Já tentei vários tipos de formatação, mas nenhuma me mostra os dados, segue da ultima forma que eu tentei:

```
txtValidadeIni.Text = Convert
                      .ToDateTime(dr["data_inicio"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Como posso converter para mostrar neste tipo de campo?

Comment: `2017-00-06` não é uma data válida!

Comment: Mas no banco de dados ela está correta 2017-10-06, ela aparece assim, só que na hora de converter, ele aparece desta forma a data 2017-00-06. Todas as formas de conversão que eu tentei utilizar, não aparece a data no textbox.

Comment: `dr` é o que ???

Comment: O que vem no `dr["data_inicio"]`?

Comment: Ele deve estar utilizando um DataReader e chamou o objeto de dr. O dr["data_inicio"] deve conter a data que ele recuperou do banco de dados.

Comment: Minha dica é verificar todas as datas que estão salvas no banco, se o erro é realmente no momento da conversão pode ter certeza que a data está chegando errada ali.

Comment: No banco de dados ele está gravada assim "2017-10-06", só que na hora de aparecer no textbox, ele não aparece, fica a configuração como se tivesse em branco dd/mm/aaaa, quando faço a depuração, ele informa este erro que informei. o dr é datareader, q estou recuperando do banco de dados.

Comment: Eu percebi que este problema ocorre apenas no Google Chrome, fiz o teste no Mozila Firefox e funcionou, não sei porque neste navegador não funciona, caso alguém tem alguma dica, agradeço.